# How should I handle large amount of facets in Algolia?

Tags: algolia

I set maxValuesPerFacet=7000, but its seems the maximum amount of facets returned is 1000. Is there a limit breaker I can use?

Im using the algoliahelper js library.

Comment: What kind of search UI do you try to implement?If you want to have a way to select any facets (even the one not retrieved) we're used to create an additional index with all facet values + small search box to search in those values in order to filter the main query afterward.

Comment: Currently I am using a search box, and loading the facets as searchable results to include the **facet count**. If I load the facets values to another index, then I would not be able to get the facet count, is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct: you won't have the count. The work-around would be to do another query on the main index for every single facet value adding a `facetFilters=myfacet:myvalue` to get the associated `nbHits`.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the help!

Comment: Algolia now has `searchForFacetValues` function for this use case. See https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/search/#search-for-facet-values